# plotly express: multiple data-series in same column -> plot in one figure

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a table with sequential y-values

```
name_a val1 
name_a val2
name_b val3 
name_b val4
```

I want to plot the y-values sequentially in a scatter or line plot and compare series "name1" against series "name2".

Sound simple, but somehow I cannot solve it.
Here is what I tried so far

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# prepare data
df = pd.read_csv(filename_results, delimiter=',', header=None)
df_subset_a = df.loc[df[1] == 'name_a']
df_subset_b = df.loc[df[1] == 'name_b']

values_a = df_subset_a.loc[:,1];
values_b = df_subset_b.loc[:,1];

fig = px.scatter(y=values_a);
```

Now how do I add the second series "values_b" to the same figure

Comment: How did the provided suggestions work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

What I observe here is there are no `x=values` in `fig = px.scatter(y=values_a);` statement. I tried to create a dummy plot with very a simple data.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.offline import iplot

X = list(range(10))
Y = list(range(10,20))

trace1 = go.Scatter(
            x=X[:5],
            y=Y[:5],
            name='plot1',

            )
trace2 = go.Scatter(
            x=X[5:],
            y=Y[5:],
            name='plot2',


                  )

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(trace1)
fig.add_trace(trace2,secondary_y=True)
fig['layout'].update(height = 600, width = 800, title = 'graph', xaxis=dict(
  tickangle=-45
))
iplot(fig)
```

Output:

[image: Plot Output]

Answer (score 0):

- it's not clear what you are trying to achieve
- have simulated a dataframe that does what you describe
- your plot does not specify **x** therefore it will be position in array passed in **y**.  Have assumed you don't actually want this,  so defined it as pandas series index
- then it's a simple case of `add_traces()` the second series traces

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# prepare data
# df = pd.read_csv(filename_results, delimiter=',', header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame({0:np.random.uniform(1,5,200), 1:np.random.choice(["name_a","name_b"], 200)})
df_subset_a = df.loc[df[1] == 'name_a']
df_subset_b = df.loc[df[1] == 'name_b']

values_a = df_subset_a.loc[:,1];
values_b = df_subset_b.loc[:,1];

px.scatter(y=values_a, x=values_a.index).add_traces(px.scatter(y=values_b, x=values_b.index).data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking at a standard dataframe of a long format, and haven't specified an index. If I'm correct, then we're just talking about a very typical [use-case for approaches such as `px.line()`](https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/). In which case, the snippet below will produce the following figure if we replace the strings `val1` with actual values:

#### Plot

[image]

#### Code

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,2,1,2],
                   'name':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                   'value':[1,2,3,4]})

fig = px.line(df, y ='value', x = 'index', color = 'name')
fig.show()
```